# How is ubuntu better than windows?

Tags: windows

Hi I'm new to ubuntu and I want to know how ubuntu is better than windows?sorry for asking such a generic question..still want to know the differences from askubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu, how do I love thee? Let me count the ways.... (we'll be here a while)

Comment: You will need to be **faaaar** more specific. Else this question will be closed **very** fast.

Comment: it is more suitable How linux is better than windows also [visit](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/)?

Comment: You should ask this on a discussion site like http://discourse.ubuntu.com/ askubuntu does not accept opinion based questions.

Comment: IMHO, this question is NOT OPINION-BASED and must NOT BE CLOSED; instead it should be answered in away that many people can see the MANY ADVANTAGES of using Ubuntu/Linux over Windows as nicely done here: http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/
I would just like to add that Ubuntu/Linux ALSO provides far more flexibility to customize NOT JUST THE DESKTOP (Appearance) but most software (e.g. **Nautilus Scripts**) to make your daily tasks much easier and faster.

Comment: I don'tuse a Microsoft Windows-based operating system and I'm not a big fan of them... But let's be honest - there are some things Microsoft does better.

The answer to your question is not a simple one, as both types of operating systems have their advantages and disadvantages...

You would be far better-off asking this question - and discussing the topic - in the official Ubuntu forums or if you would prefer a more neutral discussion, on the forums of your favorite computer/tech site.

Comment: @sadl so you expect us to know what Windows is? No thanks. Yes it is opinion based. Heck you are ASKING FOR A FLAMEWARE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu

- is free
- is free oriented, and usually there is no crappy add-ware seeking revenue from the OS
- is open source, much more transparent, and you may basically view and modify whatever you want
- relies on a very strong, reliable and efficient kernel (Linux)
- is light, and runs on machines with less ram, disk compared to Windows 8.1
- reads almost any file system, from Windows and from Mac
- is quick to install, doesn't ask for keys, doesn't call-home-check
- system-wise, all operations may be performed thanks to a terminal, script

Also since Ubuntu is free and mostly made by volunteers, manufacturers do not provide the same level of support (drivers...). So if there is one drawback that's the one: some devices may be a pita to work on Linux, some software may not have the convenience and ergonomics of paid competitors.

But, by using Ubuntu more and more, manufacturers will feel the need to provide Linux drivers.

Answer (score 1):

This question really can't be answered in any real way. Really, it's a matter of preference and opinion.

Each person is going to have their own reasons for sticking with Ubuntu. Personally, I just love how configurable and customizable everything is. Don't like Unity (the default Ubuntu desktop)? Use Gnome Shell, KDE, LXDE, etc, etc. Don't like Gedit? Install Kate, Geany, or one of the many other text editors available. Want to log in with a USB drive? Install `pamusb`. And, while every program has its own configuration options, the vast majority of them are configured via simple text files and have more options than you'd ever need.

My first experience with Linux in general was with Knoppix STD (Security Tools Distribution). I loved how I was able to directly access a disk device and, say, wipe a bootloader or whatever.

But, in my opinion, the true power of Ubuntu (or Linux in general) is the out-of-the box functionality. Bash beats the hell out of the Windows command prompt by far. If you've ever tried to write a .BAT file, you know how ungodly difficult is. Bash is much more intuitive and far more flexible than the Windows command line. Tools like `sed`, `awk`, and other tools make scripting and text file editing and modification a breeze once you learn how to use them. You just don't get tools like these on Windows.

Finally, my favorite thing about Ubuntu when I first started using it was the fact that pretty much everything you'd ever want to install was all available from one central location (Synaptic at the time, before the Software Center). This meant I didn't have to vet the trustworthiness of this program I was going to install. If it's in the Software Center, it's not spyware/a virus/going to harm my computer.

Speaking of viruses, most people can identify with the lack of viruses. I'm not saying that Linux is not susceptible to viruses, just far less so than Windows. Part of this is due to the security structure of Unix-like OSes. The other part of this equation is that, unlike Windows, a user might be running Gnome or KDE, or Firefox, Chrome or Konqueror. They could be using Evolution or Thudnerbird, or something else. In general, there's just too much variety in Linux for a virus/worm to be able to propagate reliably. Compare this to Windows where there's a very good chance people use the Windows shell (since it's a part of the kernel), Outlook, IE, etc. Since most Windows users use the same subset of programs, it makes them all more vulnerable to the same viruses.

I mean, I could go on for a long time about why Ubuntu and Linux is better than Windows. This is the tip of the iceberg. If you have a more specific question regarding a certain area that you're curious about I'll be sure to fill it in for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems off-topic & Primarily opinion based ; following may helps you:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromWindows/Philosophy
- http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy

Comment: for more search in http://ubuntuforums.org